# How to write file from sh

Tags: python, shell, sh

I have a script I like to execute in *python* via *subprocess* (yes, it has to be in `sh`).
Now I call `sh` like so:

```
subprocess.check_call( ['sh' + command] )
```

where `command` is:

```
echo 'someformat : : '${ENV_VAR}'/efc ;' > targetfile
```

Sadly this gives me:

```
sh: 0: Can't open echo 'someformat : : '${ENV_VAR}'/efc ;' > targetfile
```

Could someone please walk me through the steps to get the command working in `sh` and explain the why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
command = "echo 'someformat : : '${ENV_VAR}'/efc ;' > targetfile"
subprocess.check_call(["sh", "-c", command])
```

Parameter `-c` modifies `sh` behavior to read commands from the string of the next argument.
And arguments must be contained in list.

- [python 2 subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)
- [python 3 subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Answer (score 4):

You have to run sh with `-c` param:

```
subprocess.check_call( ['sh', '-c', command] )
```